# iOS design guidelines - tabcontrol versus list view for main/first selection screen

Tags: ios, design-guidelines

Since Apple developer account is down, I can take the chance of later submiting and getting rejected since I will then run out of time.

Suppose I have 9-11 menu items in main window navigation. It is a bit too much, but that is what customer explicitly requested.

The Android version uses a listview and it works and looks good. It does so on iOS. However, I can see most iOS  apps use a tabcontrol at bottom with extra tabs at (...) Is that a strict requirement in all cases? (I can't really say one of the menu items are more important that the other.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using a tab bar controller is not a requirement, that's a design choice. Whether to use a tab bar controller or a list view depends on how you navigate around in your app, and what you want the user experience to be. If you want the user to be able to switch easily and quickly between different modes of the app, or different views of the same data, then probably a tab bar controller would be appropriate. On the other hand, if the choices you're making initially, are not made often, and you have a large number of choices (like you do), then a table view is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really appreciate it. (Accepted it as answer now)